# In Python how do I parse the 11th and 12th bit of 3 bytes?

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bin

If I have 3 bytes `b'\x00\x0c\x00'`, which can be represented with the bits `00000000 00001100 00000000`, how do I then parse the 11th and 12th bit `11` most efficiently?

Here positions:

```
             **
00000000 11111110 22222111 tens
87654321 65432109 43210987 ones
|||||||| |||||||| ||||||||
00000000 00001100 00000000
             **
```

I have the following code:

```
bytes_input = b'\x00\x0c\x00'
for byte in bytes_input:
    print(byte, '{:08b}'.format(byte), bin(byte))
bit_position = 11-1
bits_per_byte = 8
floor = bit_position//bits_per_byte
print('floor', floor)
byte = bytes_input[floor]
print('byte', byte, type(byte))
modulo = bit_position%bits_per_byte
print('modulo', modulo)
bits = bin(byte >> modulo & 3)
print('bits', bits, type(bits))
```

Which returns:

```
0 00000000 0b0
12 00001100 0b1100
0 00000000 0b0
floor 1
byte 12 <class 'int'>
modulo 2
bits 0b11 <class 'str'>
```

Is there a computationally faster way for me to get the information that doesn't require me to calculate floor and modulo?

To put things into context I am parsing this file format:
http://pngu.mgh.harvard.edu/~purcell/plink/binary.shtml

Update 01feb2015:

Thanks to @Dunes I read the [documentation on from_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types) and found out that I can avoid doing `divmod` by just doing `int.from_bytes` with `byteorder=small`. The final function I adapted into [my code](https://github.com/team149/tc9/blob/e5040b51a467bd35b7c68f6fa92064ea3b57464e/conversion/bed2vcf.py) is `fsmall`. I can't get `timeit` to work, so I'm not sure about the relative speeds of functions.

```
bytes_input = b'\x00\x0c\x00'
bit_position = 11-1
bpb = bits_per_byte = 8

def foriginal(bytes_input, bit_position):
    floor = bit_position//bpb
    byte = bytes_input[floor]
    modulo = bit_position%bpb
    return byte >> modulo & 0b11

def fdivmod(bytes_input, bit_position):
    div, mod = divmod(bit_position, bpb)
    return bytes_input[div] >> mod & 0b11

def fsmall(bytes_input, bit_position):
    int_bytes = int.from_bytes(bytes_input, byteorder='little')
    shift = bit_position
    bits = int_bytes >> shift & 0b11
    return bits
```

Comment: Typically, bit-field parsing is done using [bit masks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). Is there a reason you can't use a mask that I'm not seeing?

Comment: `n // 8 == n >> 3` and `n % 8 == n & 7` for any n, but honestly, what are you even doing?

Comment: Thanks @aruisdante I didn't know about bit masks. I will read up on that and see if I can somehow put it to use.

Comment: @cairnarvon I am parsing a binary file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
(int.from_bytes(bytes_input, 'big') >> bit_position) & 0b11
```

It doesn't appear to be any quicker though, just terser.

However, `int.from_bytes(bytes_input, 'big')` is the most time consuming part of that code snippet by a factor 2 to 1. If you can convert your data from `bytes` to `int` once, at the beginning of the program, then you will see quicker bit masking operations.

```
In [52]: %timeit n = int.from_bytes(bytes_input, 'big')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 237 ns per loop

In [53]: %timeit n >> bit_position & 0b11
10000000 loops, best of 3: 107 ns per loop
```

Comment: kudos for using from_bytes. here's the python 2 version of that `int_from_bytes = lambda str: int(str.encode('hex'), 16)`

Comment: I can indeed convert a large chunk of the data from bytes to int once at the beginning of the program. Also see my update regarding doing byte_order='small' instead of byte_order='big'. Thanks @Dunes and the rest of you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a computationally faster way for me to get the information that doesn't require me to calculate floor and modulo?

Not really. But there is `divmod()`.

```
>>> divmod(10, 8)
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to convert your byte string into a numeric type that can be checked using a bitmask:

```
def check(b, checkbits):
    # python2 use ord(bb)
    bits = sum([bb << (8 * (len(b) - i)) for i, bb in enumerate(b,1)])
    mask = sum([2 ** (b-1) for b in checkbits])
    return bits, bits & mask == mask

bytes_input = b'\x00\x0c\x00'
checkbits = (11, 12)
bits, is_set = check(bytes_input, checkbits)
print bits, bin(bits), is_set
3072 0b110000000000 True
%timeit check(bytes_input, checkbits)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.24 µs per loop
```

I'm not sure about the timing of your code, because I couldn't get it to work.

Update: Turns out there is a faster check() implementation:

```
 def check2(b, mask):
    bits = 0
    i = 0
    for bb in b[::-1]:
        # python2 use ord(bb)
        bits |= bb << i
        i += 8
    return bits, bits & mask == mask
# we now build the mask directly
# note this is the same as 2**10 | 2**11
mask = (2**11 | 2**12) >> 1
%timeit check2(bytes_input, mask)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.82 µs per loop
```

Update 2: adopting Dunes' [nicely terse solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28257988/890242) the whole thing becomes a two-liner (note my test runs in Python 2, apparently much slower than Dune's Python3):

```
#python2 from_bytes = lambda str: int(str.encode('hex'), 16)
mask = (2**11 | 2**12) >> 1
check = lambda b, mask: int.from_bytes(b) & mask
%timeit check(bytes_input, mask)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.1 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks I think this is what I am after. You probably had problems with my code, because it's written in Python3?

Comment: The result of indexing a `bytes` object is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do binary operations in Python:

Convert the byte[s] you care about to an integer - in this case you only care about the middle byte, so we will just parse that:

```
>>> bytes_input = b'\x00\x0c\x00'
>>> middle_byte = bytes_input[1]
>>> middle_byte
12
```

Now you can do binary AND with the & operator:

```
>>> middle_int & 0x0C
12
```

To expand on this more generally, you can convert any arbitrary binary [string] to it's integer value with something like:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x0c\x00')
3072
```

And now you can apply the bitmask again:

```
>>> string_to_int(b'\x00\x0c\x00') & 0x000C00
3072
```

Comment: The question is tagged [python-3.x], which means doing `ord(middle_byte)` is unnecessary - indexing a bytes object gives you an int, not a length one byte string. Also, your `string_to_int` function already exists as a builtin called `int.from_bytes`.